# Custom uncompress function BASH

Tags: linux, encryption, compression, pipe, gzip

So, getting right to the point for a script I'm making I need to make a custom function that can take compressed data from STDIN and pipe the uncompressed data to STDOUT regardless of the type of compression.

Example:
blah blah decryption stuff | custom_uncompress | other_program

With gzip I could do: "gzip -d -c" or for lzo "lzop -d -c" but I don't know what compression it has and cannot read the magic number from the file because it's encrypted.

Comment: Do you know *anything* about the file format? You'll need to get that figured out before you start writing anything.

Comment: @duskwuff like I said I know that it is a compressed file but that is what the function is for. I need the function to find out what the stream is compressed with and stream it back out uncompressed. I just have no idea how I can get that information without using temporary files. And why the downvote?

Comment: Knowing that it's "compressed" doesn't really tell us anything. You need to know exactly what type of compression/framing/encryption was used; without that, you haven't given us enough information to even try to answer your question.

Comment: @duskwuff The encryption doesn't matter. Once it's done decrypting it is now in a compressed file format. The files may possibly be compressed in gzip, xz, lzo or bzip. The function would need to figure that out based on the format or magic numbers of the file. I just need to figure out how to do that. I have the rest down.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted in comment, it is impossible to uncompress data if one don't even know in what compressed format it is. The only best attempt one can do is to capture first couple of bytes from data stream and "guess" the result among selected common compression formats. When original data is compressed with any method not handled with this magic then it's out of luck.

This question is too unreasonable to have a proper answer.

Comment: I just need this function to get what file format it is from the magic number but I don't know how to do that taking from standard input.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have thought about that a while ago, but not entirely sure if that's a proper reason to flag a question.

Comment: @QuaDECH Save the header (maybe a hundred bytes or something), either into memory or into file, then compare the header with common formats one by one.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Got that, I flagged with same reason. "on the hook" is too much, I'm liberal on giving suggestions, but definitely won't do others' work for them.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm not asking for you guys to write me a function I'm just saying I have no idea how to do it and I need help. I thought that was the purpose of this site.

Comment: I think I'm done with this site. Thanks for the people who gave suggestions but out of all the questions I asked most of them about a week later I ended up finding and using my own workaround. I guess I'm just not good at putting my questions into text.

Comment: @QuaDECH In your question you say that you can't read the magic number because the file is encrypted, but then you say in the comments that the encryption doesn't matter, because you've done that part already. You need to clarify what you have and what you don't have in order to get better answers. It also helps if you reword you question to be clear that you don't expect someone to write the code for you. If you do that, then it will be a good question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. In my example it (sort of) shows that the decrypted data flows into a data stream. My actual file is encrypted however the compressed stream isn't (because it is decrypted into the stream). I would somehow need to get the magic number out of the stream of data, pick a decompresser and put that back into the stream where other_program could use the uncompressed data. And I can't use temporary files because it would slow down the program too much and I'm dealing with big files. Idk if this is making sense but I can't think of another way to explain it.